# Bitmap:Out of Memory Exception

Tags: android, exception, bitmap

I am creating a face detector app where image is stored using bitmap.There is no such error in the code but when running on device it shows an exception.Following is the Logcat details.Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

```
 11-06 15:50:49.340: D/dalvikvm(32555): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 43K, 8% free 12131K/13059K, paused 21ms, total 25ms
    11-06 15:50:49.390: I/dalvikvm-heap(32555): Grow heap (frag case) to 22.111MB for 10036240-byte allocation
    11-06 15:50:49.425: D/dalvikvm(32555): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 21931K/22919K, paused 14ms+2ms, total 35ms
    11-06 15:50:49.730: D/dalvikvm(32555): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 5% free 21932K/22919K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
    11-06 15:50:49.920: I/dalvikvm-heap(32555): Grow heap (frag case) to 60.396MB for 40144912-byte allocation
    11-06 15:50:49.940: D/dalvikvm(32555): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 61136K/62151K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 20ms
    11-06 15:50:50.310: D/dalvikvm(32555): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9802K, 18% free 51335K/62151K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
    11-06 15:50:50.310: I/dalvikvm-heap(32555): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 20072464-byte allocation
    11-06 15:50:50.325: D/dalvikvm(32555): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 18% free 51326K/62151K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
    11-06 15:50:50.325: E/dalvikvm-heap(32555): Out of memory on a 20072464-byte allocation.
    11-06 15:50:50.325: I/dalvikvm(32555): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
    11-06 15:50:50.325: I/dalvikvm(32555):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41982508 self=0x419728e8
    11-06 15:50:50.325: I/dalvikvm(32555):   | sysTid=32555 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074306864
    11-06 15:50:50.330: I/dalvikvm(32555):   | schedstat=( 683836904 179752181 2016 ) utm=39 stm=29 core=3
    11-06 15:50:50.335: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at android.media.FaceDetector.<init>(FaceDetector.java:~121)
    11-06 15:50:50.335: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at com.example.facedetection.FaceDetection$MyView.<init>(FaceDetection.java:56)
    11-06 15:50:50.335: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at com.example.facedetection.FaceDetection.onCreate(FaceDetection.java:23)
    11-06 15:50:50.355: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
    11-06 15:50:50.355: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
    11-06 15:50:50.360: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
    11-06 15:50:50.360: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
    11-06 15:50:50.360: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
    11-06 15:50:50.360: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
    11-06 15:50:50.360: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-06 15:50:50.365: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    11-06 15:50:50.365: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    11-06 15:50:50.365: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-06 15:50:50.370: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-06 15:50:50.370: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    11-06 15:50:50.370: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
    11-06 15:50:50.370: I/dalvikvm(32555):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-06 15:50:50.370: D/AndroidRuntime(32555): Shutting down VM
    11-06 15:50:50.370: W/dalvikvm(32555): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419812a0)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.media.FaceDetector.<init>(FaceDetector.java:121)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at com.example.facedetection.FaceDetection$MyView.<init>(FaceDetection.java:56)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at com.example.facedetection.FaceDetection.onCreate(FaceDetection.java:23)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
    11-06 15:50:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(32555):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You need to optimize memory in your application. To save memory you should recycle bitmap and release them. In your case bit map is eating up most of the memory. Lot of things need to optimize the memory
1.Down sample the image. 
2.Reallocate the bitmap after the usage.
3.Add large heap parameter in your manifest(In your case this is not needed).

Answer (score 0):

Please recycle the bitmap after usage like this:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {   
        cleanUp();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void cleanUp()
    {   
        if(bmp!=null){
            bmp.recycle();
            bmp=null;
        }
        if(realBmp!=null){
            realBmp.recycle();
            realBmp=null;
        }      
        System.gc();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you Bitmap did its work successfully, at that time do, bitmap recycle and assignit to null.

```
Bitmap bitmap;
```

After your work done with Bitmap.

```
bitmap.recycle();
bitmap=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to recycle the bitmap that you are not going to use anymore. Also you can try to read this to load efficiently the bitmaps: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html